# How to stop ProgressDialog and Thread?

Tags: java, android

i am new to android development. i created an sample map application, once we enter the location code, ProgressDialog will be shown while the location is loading. Once the location is displayed, ProgressDialog is to be dismissed, but it keeps on going even after the location is displayed in background.
Below is my code.

```
Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            if(webLocation == true){
                                progressDialog.dismiss();


                            }
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                              e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
                });
            background.start();

            }
```

can anyone give me a solution for stopping the ProgressDialog, once the location is shown. i can't get an idea for this solution, if anyone has some ideas or solution, it will be helpful for me.

Comment: What is `webLocation`? Are you using Thread just to show AlertDialog?

Comment: use asynctask it will easy

Comment: Try `webLocation == true`, you're using only single `=`.

Comment: Use ProgressDialog.dimsiss(); to stop progressDialog... Thread will stop automatically once it finishes all its methods.

Comment: Thanks guys for sharing your ideas, i tried the ideas you gave but still progresDialog keeps on running even after the required location in map is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
 if(webLocation = true)
```

by

```
 if(webLocation == true) or if (webLocation)
```

You're basically assigning the value `true` to variable `webLocation`. You should compare, so use `==`.

You should better use `AsyncTask` class rather than thread with sleep of 5 seconds (which is hardcoded value).

1) `onPreExecute()` do the following `progressDialog.show()`

2)Get the location in `doInBackGround` method. After thar `onPostExecute` will be called, in this method do the following

```
   if (progressDialog.isShowing())
       progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
    } 
catch (InterruptedException e) {

                                  e.printStackTrace();

                        }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                        .
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        enter code here
         if(webLocation = true){
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();


                                }
                            }
                        });



                    }
                    });
                background.start();

                }
```